# Delete/edit/add a line of text from a text file

Tags: vb.net, replace, text-files

My starting code would read all the lines from a textfile and placing them in an array

```
Public textArray As String()
textArray = File.ReadAllLines("textfile.txt")
```

I want to be able to delete a line of text, edit a line of text and add a line text to the textfile. My idea would be displaying all the lines of text in rows where I could click one line and the text will be placed in a textbox, from that textbox I can edit the text. 
Delete, edit and add would be three separate buttons.

I need a starting code, I am confused on how to start this.

Comment: There is much going on here. Your dumping the whole text file in an array,but if you want per line this wont work. For your solution can you just dump it. Into a rich textbox field change what you need to and then resave it?

Comment: yes that will do... never thought of that. would be much faster and easier. but can i have a starting code for it? thanks.

Comment: If you just want to know how to properly read from and write to text files, you should look into this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A listbox would be well suited to your task.  Loading the file is as simple as using the AddRange method of the items collection, `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("textfile.txt"))`.

Saving the data is just as simple with File.WriteAllLines, `File.WriteAllLines("textfile.txt", ListBox1.Items)`.

To edit the data you can use buttons and read the selected line in the listbox or you can handle the selected indexchanged event

Comment: this is what i am looking for. but is it possible for me to add new lines while using the ListBox?

Comment: The ListBox.Items has methods where you can Add, Remover, Insert, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a `Streamreader` and `ReadLine()` for reading all lines and a `List` for saving them.

So the code for the reading + saving would be:

```
Dim lineList As New List(Of String)()

Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)

    Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
         lineList.add(sr.ReadLine())
    Loop
```

Then add some labels (with the text) to your form:

```
For i as Integer = 0 to lineList.Count - 1
    Dim Label as New Label
    lineLabel.Text = lineList.Item(i)
    lineLabel.Location = New Point(0, 50 * i) 'you can change the 50 to whatever value you want
    Me.Controls.Add(Label)
    AddHandler Label.Click, AddressOf Me.Label_Click 'here we add a handler for the label-clicks
Next
```

The handler will look like this then:

```
 Private Sub Label_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'handle the label clicks here
 End Sub
```

Comment: When using SteamReader, it's goot to use `Using ... End Using`, to avoid the file staying opened and disallowing other functions to write to it.